# What is wrong with my code for CS50 Caesar problem?

Tags: c, cs50

This problem aims to apply Caesar Cipher. The goal is to encrypt a user defined message. The problem requires us to get the key using the command prompt. After getting the message and the key we must encrypt each character by moving by the key. e.g. if the key is 1 then A - B and b - c and z - a, if the key is 2 then a - c, D - F etc... I have made a very solid program and it seems very correct yet when I use the check50 to check my code it appears so many errors yet the outputs are the same... I just don't get what's wrong with my code..

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; argv[1][i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(argv[1][i]))
        {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
             return 1;
        }
    }

    int key = atoi(argv[1]);

    string ptext;

    ptext = get_string("plaintext: ");

    printf("ciphertext: ");

    int n = strlen(ptext);

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (isupper(ptext[i]))
        {
            printf("%c", (((ptext[i] + key) - 65) % 26) + 65);
        }
        else if (islower(ptext[i]))
        {
            printf("%c", (((ptext[i] + key) - 97) % 26) + 97);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", ptext[i]);
        }

    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

link to check50
https://submit.cs50.io/check50/f7714d6b10c0b2e9fd1c1f01f4209195d8dc5163

Comment: Please include the relevant inputs and outputs in the question as text, not as links to external sites. What is the input that fails? What is the expected output? What is the actual output?

Comment: Looks like an output issue.  What happens if you get rid of the `printf("\n");` at the end of the loop?

Comment: Don’t edit the question so the answer becomes inaccurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're outputting the null terminator character.

```
    int n = strlen(ptext);

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
```

You should only loop to `i < n`.

Comment: OMG thanks so much such a careless mistake..